# Stage which prevents another one

Tags: java, libgdx

I made a stage for beginning the game and made one more for end of the game.

There are images which have `clickListener` events on the stages.

My problem is : **Stage 1(first)** works well, then **gameover** and **gameover** leads to **stage2**. But when I click images on stage 2(last one), It does not work.My guess is that stage 1 covers stage2 and prevents stage2's buttons to work.

Am I right ? or what could be the actual reason behind the issue and how can I solve?

Comment: Do you set Stage 2 as input processor via `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()` on gameOver?

Comment: Ah really :( I did it in Create but I realized that I need to write it stage2's section. really thank youu